# How to prevent certain users from accessing a route and any subroutes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, authorization

What's the best way to prevent a particular user from accessing a route and any of its subroutes in `react-router`?

e.g. I have a route `/admin/` and it has many other subroutes like `/admin/create-user`, `/admin/settings`, etc.

Is there another way of preventing users from accessing these routes without indicating on each component some condition like so?

```
if (user.role.name !== "Admin") {
    return (
      <div className="error-page">
        <h1>Sorry, you don't have rights to access this page.</h1>
     </div>
    );
  } else {
  // render admin component
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a custom ProtectedRoute component, and pass the required role to this whether the user can go to that route or not.

Codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-protect-route-roles-z7j3l

ProtectedRoute.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import {user} from "./AuthService";

export const ProtectedRoute = ({
  path,
  component: Component,
  render,
  requiredRole,
  ...rest
}) => {

  return (
    <Route
      path={path}
      {...rest}
      render={props => {
        if (user.role.name === requiredRole) {
          return Component ? <Component {...props} /> : render(props);
        } else {
          return <Redirect to="/error" />;
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

The AuthService is simply like this, you need to modify it to fit your requirements.

AuthService.js (you can change the role to Admin, to play with it)

```
export const user = {
  name: "User 1",
  role:{
    name: "User"
  }
}
```

App.js (Please note that we are using out ProtectedRoute component, and passing the required role to it)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import User from "./User";
import Admin from "./Admin";
import Login from "./Login";
import ErrorPage from "./ErrorPage";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/user">User</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/admin">Admin</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/error" component={ErrorPage} />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/user" component={User} requiredRole="User" />
          <ProtectedRoute path="/admin" component={Admin} requiredRole="Admin" />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

With this setup, a user without Admin role cannot navigate to Admin and it's nested routes.

Answer (score 0):

use the Route component as shown

```
if(user.role.name !== "Admin") {
   <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
} else {
   <Redirect to="/" />
}
```

if Admin show the component else redirect to home.