# How to keep user logged in frontend?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, web, frontend, react-fullstack

So I am a new developer working on some personal projects.
I want to keep a user logged-in in my react web app
Below is how I implemented it
Basically if the user logs in then the jwt token will get stored in cookie of the browser and if there is jwt token cookie in user's browser then user will get access to particular routes.
If browser doesnt find any cookie with auth token then the user will get access to only landing page and login page
Is it an acceptable implementation?
If not, why? and how can i improve it?

```
import './App.css';
import {
  useNavigate,
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  useLocation,
  Navigate
} from "react-router-dom";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';
import { React, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Login from './Pages/Login/Login';
import ProfilePage from './Pages/UserProfile/UserProfile';
import Footer from './Components/footer/Footer';
import Home from './Pages/Home/Home';
import Landing from './Pages/Landing/Landing';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar/Navbar';

function Main() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const currentRoute = location.pathname;

  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const authToken = Cookies.get('authToken');
    if (authToken) {
      setIsAuthenticated(true);
    }
  }, []);


  return (
    <>
      {currentRoute !== "/login" && <Navbar />}

      <Routes>
        {isAuthenticated ? (
          <>
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
            <Route path="/search" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/profile" element={<ProfilePage />} />
            {/* <Route path="/chat" element={<Chat />} /> */}
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Route path="/" element={<Landing />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
          </>
        )}
      </Routes>
      
      {currentRoute !== "/login" && <Footer />}
    </>
  )
}

export default Main;
```

```
//App.js
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Main from './Main.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Main />
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: The implementation that you mentioned is accepted and correct, you could check this question which has a similar idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426338/react-js-how-to-handle-authentication

Are you struggling with running the code or is it just the idea?